# Passing result of tr as second parameter in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, process-substitution

My command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next;} substr($0,50,6) in a' file1 file2
```

The problem is that file 2 contains `\000` characters and awk consider it as binary file.

Replacing `\000` with space character:

```
tr '\000' ' ' < file2 > file2_not_binary
```

solves binary file problem.

However my file2 is a 20GB file. And I don't want to do `tr` separately and save result as another file. I want to pass the result of `tr` to `awk`.

I have tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next;} substr($0,50,6) in a' file1 < (tr '\000' ' ' < file2)
```

But the result is:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Another question is:  can my memory or awk handle such a big file at once? I'm working on 12GB RAM PC.

**EDIT**

One of the answer works as I expected (credits to Ed Morton)

```
tr '\000' ' ' < file2 | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} substr($0,50,6) in a' file1 -
```

However it is like 2 time slower then doing the same in 2 steps - first removing `\000` and save it and then using `awk` to search. How I can speed it up?

**EDIT2**

My bad. Ed Morton solution is actually a little bit faster then doing the same in two separately commands.

Two commands separately: `08:37:053`

Two commands piped: `08:07:204`

Comment: When you say `it is like 2 time slower` - what is `it` in that statement, the awk command or the sum of the `tr` + `awk` commands? It's hard to believe that creating an intermediate file would be faster than the pipe so please [edit] your question to show the 3rd-run (to avoid caching variances) results of these 2 command lines: `time { tr '\000' ' ' < file2 > file3 && awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} substr($0,50,6) in a' file1 file3; }` and `time { tr '\000' ' ' < file2 | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} substr($0,50,6) in a' file1 -; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since awk isn't storing your 2nd file in memory the size of that file is irrelevant except for speed of execution. Try this:

```
tr '\000' ' ' < file2 | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} substr($0,50,6) in a' file1 -
```

Comment: Thank you Ed for nice code, could you please let me know about - at last of command is it means read the standard output of first command as second Input_file, will be grateful to you if you could let me know on same.

Comment: Any UNIX command can accept `-` as an argument in place of stdin so when you say `cmd file -` it's telling the command `cmd` to read `file` first and then stdin.

Comment: I have a question about 2nd command. If I will do `cut -c 50-55 file2` comparison will obviously work but what will be returned as the result? I want a whole line from file2 but I'm afraid that only result of cut will be returned as there result of `cut` + `awk`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right so don't do that. I'll remove that suggestion. That's the problem when you don't provide any sample input/output for us to test with - all you can get from us are untested guesses at what might work.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
awk ... <(tr -d '\0' < file2)
# -------^ no space!
```

Check the manual about [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could replace it in awk using `gsub(/\000/," ")`. Testing, let's make a test file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "a b\000c d"}' > foo
$ hexdump -C foo
00000000  61 20 62 00 63 20 64 0a                           |a b.c d.|
00000008
```

And then:

```
$ awk '{print; gsub(/\000/," "); print}' foo
a bc d
a b c d
```

Comment: this is not in fact FS. I want to replace it with space only to not change the length of line. Each line need to be fixed length.

Comment: I have tried: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next;} {gsub(/\000/," ");if (substr($0,51,6) in a) {print $0};} ' file1 file2` but it started complaining about `awk: line 0 (NR=1128): file is binary` again

Comment: Which awk is that?

Comment: version : 3.1.7

Comment: `BINMODE` is gawk-specific to allow awk to read/write `\r`s on non-UNIX systems, e.g. I use BINMODE=3 on cygwin when appropriate so my scripts can see `\r`s which would otherwise be stripped out by the underlying C primitives. Gawk won't have a problem with NUL chars in the input with or without that option but other awks will have a problem that you cannot fix within an awk script because they use C-style strings in their implementation and those are terminated by NUL chars which is why they won't let you read a string that contains a NUL char as that's impossible to represent internally.